# shell script - open xterm window execute command and keep on executing script

Tags: bash, shell, sh, xterm

Im writing a shell script and i need my script to open a xterm window run a command and without closing the xterm proceed with the script.

The code is basically a huge case for a menu.

This is an example of my script

```
...
example() {
echo -n "thingy > "
read thingy
echo -n "thingy1> "
read thingyl
xterm -hold -e *el command*
menux  
}
...
```

Problem:

The script opens xterm executes the command and keeps the window open but wont continue the script and if i press ctrl + c it goes back to the shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This change

```
nohup xterm -hold -e *el command* &
```

Will do what you want.  The `nohup` tells the shell not to send the HUP (1) signal to this child process when the parent exits.  The `&` makes the `xterm` command run in the background so that the script can continue. `man nohup` has details.

If you want to do away with the output, then the following will divert all the output to `/dev/null` and the `2>&1` will make sure that `stderr` is directed to the same place.  If you want to see your errors, then do not perform that second redirection.

```
nohup xterm -hold -e *el command* > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

`man bash` has details on redirection.

Comment: its works but how can i hide the nohup message (nohup: appending output to ‘nohup.out’) and stop it from saving the.out file?

Comment: Happy to be helpful!